# use java connect Atlas MongoDB failed

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

when I use java driver to connect atlas mongodb db，got a SSLHandshakeException，how to fix it？

```
      final ConnectionString  uriString = new ConnectionString ("mongodb+srv://XXX:XXX@cluster0-ddtis.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");  
      MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);        
      MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

      System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");  

      MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("movie");

      String dbs = mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().first();
      System.out.println("dbs" + dbs);
```

> 2019-10-01 00:03:23 INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster:76] Exception in
>   monitor thread while connecting to server
>   cluster0-shard-00-02-ddtis.azure.mongodb.net:27017
>   com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:551)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:433)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:273)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:257)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:129)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959) at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
>   at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026) at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072) at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
>   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:757)
>   at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99)
>   at
>   com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:430)
>   ... 9 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
>   at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
>   at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
>   at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
>   ... 18 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
>   at
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
>   at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
>   at
>   sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
>
> ### ... 24 common frames omitted

Comment: Take a look at this document: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/

Comment: Which MongoDB Java driver version are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason can be root certificate issue not being present in cacerts of your jre/lib/security/ folder and hence SSL issue.
Can you try to save and import the following certificates using keytool and test :
"ISRG Root X1: https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem.txt
(IdenTrust) DST Root CA X3: [https://letsencrypt.org/certs/trustid-x3-root.pem.txt"](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/trustid-x3-root.pem.txt%22)

The mongodb manual provides the above certificate links to import for any connectivity issues and here is doc link:
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/faq/security/#tls-change-hard-code.